# Cannot grant permissions when facebook desktop app perform login process

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

I'm newbie in facebook api. I follow this docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3

when I pass this link https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=617640518361609&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages to webview

and login with a facebook account, it's not grant manage_pages and publish_pages to my app, just public_profie
[image]

where am I wrong?

Comment: are you trying with an app admin/developer/tester?

Comment: Those extended permissions are asked for on the _second screen_ of the login dialog … you have to click “Okay” in the screen that’s shown in your image, only after that it will ask your for manage_pages and publish_pages.

Comment: when i click okay, nothing happen like you said.

Comment: @user2582163 Did you get the permission to ask every time. I am having same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

> **Which Permissions Require Review?**
>
> - Review is not required to ask for the three basic permissions: public_profile, user_friends and email.
> - Review is required to ask for any other permissions when people log into your app

If you're using a admin/developer/tester user of your app, you should be able to request the permissions anyway.

Comment: snap, 5 seconds too slow :) - ah well, upvoting yours instead. it´s better anyway...

Comment: You can't be lucky all the time :-) But it's a shame that FB removed the part of the docs which notices people about the adin/developer/tester thing...

Comment: i confuse, if i'm not submit my App for Login Review, permissions that i ask to user log into my app will not work?

Comment: it's not true, there are many app can ask these permissions when you log in facebook with their app. i think my app is wrong in setting or somethings  i dont know yet.

Comment: No, first they need to go under the Login Review. It's all in the docs. Believe it or not.